# How to find field through foreign key in cakephp3.x.x?

Tags: php, cakephp, foreign-key-relationship, cakephp-3.0, cakephp-model

[image: My index.ctp is like this]

[image: My Sample Database Design]

how to try like this, i already write  in ItemsTable.php like this

```
public function initialize(array $config) {
        $this->belongsTo('Categories', [
            'className' => 'Item',
            'foreignKey' => 'cid',
            'propertyName' => 'name'
        ]);
}
```

How do I display category name instead of `Cid`?

Comment: You need to show us a bit more of your code as it is not very clear what you are doing. When you fetch your items the category name should be in something like `$item['Category']['name']`.

Comment: Maybe the `contain` options is what you are looking for. Check http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#getting-a-single-entity-by-primary-key

Comment: I want to show Cateogry Name instead of Cid(fk).This is Sample Project to Learn Cakephp3.x.x version @Annabel