# CakePHP: Use foreign key to display related data in view

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp-3.0

I'm new to CakePHP (using version 3). I completed Cake's blog tutorial and have been experimenting with some customizations. One that has me stumped is adding a Category column to the Articles table. I can add the category ID, but I'd prefer the category name.

I set up a "belongs to" relationship in the Articles model:

```
class ArticlesTable extends Table
```

{

```
public function initialize(array $config)
{
    parent::initialize($config);
    $this->table('articles');
    $this->displayField('title');
    $this->primaryKey('id');
    $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');
    $this->belongsTo('Categories', [
        'foreignKey' => 'category_id',
    ]);
}
```

I also used the set() method for categories in the Articles controller:

```
    public function index()
{
    $articles = $this->paginate($this->Articles);
    $this->set(compact('articles'));
    $this->set('_serialize', ['articles']);
    $this->set(compact('categories'));
}
```

Here's what I have in my Articles index view:

```
<?php foreach ($articles as $article): ?>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <?= $article->category_id ?>
            </td>
            <td>...
```

I tried replacing "$article->category_id" with a few different things, but have had no success. My best guess was the following:

```
$article['Categories']['id']
```

That just leaves an empty column, though. What am I doing wrong?

P.S. I found a similar (but unanswered) question here:

[How to find field through foreign key in cakephp3.x.x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27718675/how-to-find-field-through-foreign-key-in-cakephp3-x-x)

Comment: can you show the debug value of $articles within your index function ? Try debug($articles); in index function and post what comes there ..

Comment: @Jacek has shown how to do it in this case. @Manohar has provided a helpful hint for how to solve problems of this type whenever you run into them; make `debug` and `pr` your best friends!

Comment: Thanks, Manohar and Greg! While it seems obvious in hindsight, it hadn't occurred to me to use debug functions. For anyone else who, like me, could benefit from from some Cake debugging knowledge, here's a handy link:

http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/debugging.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Model/Table/ArticlesTable.php**

```
class ArticlesTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        ...
        $this->belongsTo('Categories', [
            'foreignKey' => 'category_id',
        ]);
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

**Model/Table/CategoriesTable.ph**p

```
class CategoriesTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        ...
        $this->hasMany('Articles', [
            'foreignKey' => 'category_id',
        ]);
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

**Controller/ArticlesController.php**

```
public function index()
{
    $this->paginate = [
        'contain' => ['Categories']
    ];

    $articles = $this->paginate($this->Articles);

    $this->set(compact('articles'));
    $this->set('_serialize', ['articles']);
}
```

**Template/Articles/index.ctp**

```
<?php foreach ($articles as $article): ?>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <?= $article->category->name ?>
        </td>
     <td>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

[Here you can read more about Associations](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html)

Comment: Thank you, Jacek! That did the trick. I had seen the Cake page on Associations, but it seemed a little short on the controller and view aspects. Now that I've seen your solution, it looks like this is what I was missing:

http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/pagination.html#joining-additional-associations